# Proving that this family of functions is Compact

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness

The following question is from Ponnusamy and silvermann Complex Variables with applications.( Page 395) and I am struck on part of question 7.

> Let F be the family consisting of all the functions f(z) that are analytic in a domain D with |f(z)|$\leq M$ inD. Show that F is compact and normal family in D.

I have proved family to be normal but struck on compact.

Can u please help?

Comment: It can't possibly be compact, can it? If we equip the vector space of analytic complex functions on a compact domain $D$, then we can equip the $\infty$-norm to this space, in such a way that $F$ becomes the closed ball of radius $M$. If this were compact, then this would imply the analytic functions on $D$ would have to be finite-dimensional, which is patently absurd. Unless I'm missing something, it seems $F$ is frequently **not** compact.

Comment: @Theo usually the metric is the one that induces uniform convergence on compacts not the supremum one, and indeed the family is compact trivially since by normality (and Montel) any sequence has a normally convergent subsequence, but if $f_n \to f$ obviously $|f| \le M$, so the limit is in the family

Comment: @Conrad Ah, yep, that tracks. I'm too down on sleep.

Comment: @theo no problem - usually normal in this context is equivalent to precompact, so the only question is if limits are in the family and that raises subtle issues (for example the family of holomorphic self maps of the open unit disc is normal but not compact since one can have circle constants as limits of such eg $f(z)=1, |z|<1$ which are not in the original family- adding those gives raise to the Schur class which is compact; the $S$ family of normalized univalent functions on the unit disc $z+...$ is normal by basic estimates and compact by Hurwitz and the fact that $f'(0)=1$)

Comment: @Conrad I think proving it normal  was sufficient because it means that each {$f_n$} has a subsequence {$f_{n_k}$} converging uniformly and hence converging. Am I right?

Comment: Compact means that the limit is in the family and here it is indeed but there are cases as in my comment above where it may not be, so normal in general is just precompact

Comment: @Conrad So, how should I prove it compact?

Comment: Here it is automatic since the limit preserves non strict inequalities and your family is defined  by such